# Problem Deploying Asp.net hybrid application in IIS 7

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I integrated my MVC application in to an existing Web Forms application. Both the web forms part and mvc part runs perfectly in visual web development server, when i tried to deploy it in IIS 7, web forms part is working, but not the MVC, can anyone suggest me what could be wrong??

I have already done the necessary steps such as

1. Making sure System.Web.Mvc, System.Web.Routing and System.Web.Astractions are available.
2. Application is deployed in Integrated Pipeline Mode.
3. validateIntegratedMode set to false in web.config

Do I need any specific handlers when we deploy an hybrid app with both mvc and web forms, cause i deployed an mvc only application before in the same server on IIS 7 which works perfectly.

I get a 404 error, when i try to open a page in MVC, like this one

Description: The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.
Error Code: 0x80070002
Notification: MapRequestHandler
Module: IIS Web Core
RequestedURL: http://10.242.22.1/Sales/Index

I would really appreciate any suggestions, my global.asax is very plain, it has the same default routing that is generated by default when a new mvc app is created.

Jay

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed MVC on your server. If yes, change Application pool to interation mode. Following link might help http://www.hanselman.com/blog/PlugInHybridsASPNETWebFormsAndASPMVCAndASPNETDynamicDataSideBySide.aspx

Comment: I have bin deployed the required assemblies as suggested in the following link, instead of installing mvc on my server: http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/03/bin-deploy-aspnetmvc.aspx, wouldnt that be enough? And Yes, my application pool is in integrated mode, also i ran a simple plain mvc app on the same server by bin deploying it, it worked fine, problem came in when i tried to deploy the hybrid

Comment: btw, im using .net 3.5 sp1, any ideas, still have the same problem :(

Comment: got it working, i shouldnt run it in integrated mode, i ran it in classic mode, added a wildscript map, and both work fine... quite simple, yet took a day to figure out